# regexp - lazy mode not working

Tags: php, regex

My string is here:

```
<li>super strona <em>{cena:100 zł netto}</em></li><li>foo strona <em>{cena:101 zł netto}</em></li></ul></p><h3>Strona super {cena:101 zł netto}</h3>
```

..and I want to change it using regexp to this:

```
<li>super strona <em>100 zł netto</em></li><li>foo strona <em>101 zł netto</em></li></ul></p><h3>Strona super 101 zł netto</h3>
```

I'm trying to do it this way:
search: `{cena:(.*?)}`
replace: `\1`

but it doesn't work properly. Here is an effect:

```
<li>super strona <em>100 zł netto}</em></li><li>foo strona <em>{cena:101 zł netto</em></li></ul></p><h3>Strona super 101 zł netto</h3>
```

To replace text I'm using PHP's ereg_replace() function.

Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: As a general advice, use preg instead of ereg.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
 $text = preg_replace('#\{cena:([^\}]*)\}#', '\\1', $text);
```

You need to escape `{` and `}` as they are part of quantors within regex. I also would advise not to use the `ereg*` functions as they have been proven to be extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
\{cena:[^\}]*\}
```

try to replace with regex above, see if it helps.